# SpringApplication not able to instantiate bean

Tags: java, spring, web-services

I am new to Spring & WebService and trying a few guides on Spring.io.
I planned to create a basic RESTful WebService which consumes Google Direction API and returns just the status.

Here are the classes:

- Resource

  ```
  @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown=true)
  public class Direction {

      // getters & setters

      public Direction() {
          super();
      }

      private String status;

      public String toString() {
      return status;
      }
  }
  ```
- Controller

  ```
   @Controller
   public class Consumer {

       public Consumer() {
               super();
       }

       @Resource
       private String url;
       @Resource
       private RestTemplate client;
       @Resource
       private String apiKey;

       @RequestMapping(value = "/directions", method=RequestMethod.GET)
       public @ResponseBody Direction consume(@RequestParam(value="source") String source, @RequestParam(value="destination") String destination) {

       return consumeDirections(buildURI(source, destination));
       }

           // Builds URI
       private String buildURI(...) {
           ...
       }

       private Direction consumeDirections(final String requestURI) {
           return client.getForObject(requestURI, Direction.class);
       }
    }
  ```
- Configuration v1

  ```
  @Configuration
  @ComponentScan
  @EnableAutoConfiguration
  public class Application {

      public static void main(String[] args) {
          SpringApplication.run(Consumer.class, args);
      }
  }
  ```
- Springconfig 
  http://pastebin.com/dsNVBWQq

Spring returns that No qualifying bean of type [java.lang.String] found for dependency.
This happens for all the beans in Consumer.

However, this works Configuration v2

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class Application {
    @Resource
    private Consumer consumer;

    public void execute() {
        System.out.println(consumer.consume("x", "z"));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ConfigurableApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("application-config.xml");
    context.getBean(Application.class).execute();
    }
}
```

Some observations

1. @Resouce(Explicitly define bean) doesnt work for v1
2. SpringApplication is not aware of the Springconfig and fails during bean instantiation

I would like to understand why this issue crops up and how to resolve it?

Comment: where have you defined `apiKey` and `url` in v1

Comment: @Jaiwo99: Its in the Spring-config. I have not touched Spring config for both the versions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is very easy, the xml config is not loaded. have a look at [Spring-Boot: XML Config](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#using-boot-importing-xml-configuration)

if you don't wanna touch existing xml, you need another @configuration annotated class and @ImportResource to load the xml configuration, just like the document says.

IMO, you don't need apiKey and url in the config, you should annotate them with @value, and define them in a .properties file. There are also default settings of spring boot, you get take advantage of it. like, name the properities application.properities and put it on classpath, spring boot will load it automatically.

Comment: Thanks.

I did understand that the Spring config wasn't being read but was searching for ways to load it. This is exactly what was needed.